# Given x & y, determine if it is within a specific cardioid.

Tags: geometry

Given a cardioid with a = 10; cusp at the origin and oriented vertically; and point x,y; determine if p is in the cardioid.

Presumably I start with the parametric equation:

x = a cos t (1 - cos t)
y = a sin t (1 - cos t)

But where to go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio $\frac{y}{x}$ gives $\tan t$, hence $t$. Once you have $t$, you just have to check if $$(a\cos t(1-\cos t),a\sin t(1-\cos t))$$
matches $(x,y)$ or not.

Comment: That's the answer I understand -- it defines what the mysterious t is -- thanks. I'd vote, but clicking the arrows does nothing. Just a shame I can't copy&paste the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Polar coordinates helps: $r\le 2a(1+\cos \varphi)$ is within the cardioid.
Where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\, \cos\varphi=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just compare your radius $ \sqrt{ x_1^2 +y_1^2 }$ with $ a ( 1 - \cos t ),$ given in polar form.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

the cartesian equation is:

$$
(x^2+y^2+ax)^2=a^2(x^2+y^2)
$$

See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cardioid.html).